# Read word by word a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

i don't know whether this question has already been asked but i couldn't find anything about this.
I have a UITextView and i would like to be able to read single words from a text written by the users. This is an example:

i write on a textView this:

> Obiwan is cool

then i have something like 3 string and store the single words that would result

```
string_1 = "Obiwan";
string_2 = "is";
string_3 = "cool";
```

What i'm looking for is like the Java's

```
s.useDelimiter(" ");
```

plus, to read the tableView,

```
while(s.hasNext()){
...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use NSString's equivalent of Java's split(), which is either

```
componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
```

or

```
componentsSeparatedByString:
```

Both of these return an NSArray of word strings. If you pass a single space to the latter, it will do exactly what your Java example does. However, if you want to be more precise by including other whitespace and newlines, you use the former with an NSCharacterSet, like

```
NSArray *words = [self.textView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!i'm doing this  `NSArray *words = [self.myTextView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];` but how can i deal with this NSArray? i would save the single words in a multidimensional array to iterate and print the strings at my will.